# On supersolvability of a finite group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G \cong (\Bbb{Z}_q \times \Bbb{Z}_q) \rtimes \Bbb{Z}_p$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes number with $p| q-1$.

Why $G$ is supersolvable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a result of [Chris Pinnock](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwi8iNnjrPTUAhVEOBQKHWVsA7QQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdfs.semanticscholar.org%2F7b18%2Fdbd4f663c9863c35d5c42774f7ec0808ad41.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEc4Ig4upW1z3jwYIAqWzjxkvy3eA) (1998), Corollary $4.5$, every group $G$ of order $pq^b$ with primes $p,q$ satisfying $p\mid (q-1)$ is supersolvable. This is related to Burnsides $p^aq^b$-Theorem.

Comment: Thanks Dear Dietrich Burde,  where i can find this result?

Comment: Click on the link! Then search Corollary $4.5$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dear Dietrich Burde